# With Cheerio, how do I select a node which has a data-some-attribute but with no value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cheerio

I'm using Cheerio, and trying to select

```
<div data-featured-img="" class="relative w-full" style="padding-bottom: 55.25%;">
                <iframe title="sometitle" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/avid123?start=3720&amp;feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
            </div>
```

but I've tried to use the jQuery way, which would be `jQuery("div[data-featured-img]")[0]` but that doesn't work with Cheerio. How can I do this? I tried Jquery way bc I heard Jquery and Cheerio have similar selectors.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That does work with cheerio. If it's not finding it that's because it's not there.